# Best way to dynamically add / remove views in Prism + Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, prism

Does Prism have built-in support for having "groups" of views? If so, how is it done? What I'd like to do is have one regin, call it WizardRegion, where I can have different types of wizards load into that region. Let's assume I have two different wizards: signup and dowork. And each wizard has four pages or views. If I do the normal RegisterViewWithRegion() for each view then all eight views will be visible all the time. When I switch to the signup wizard I want the four views for signup to show. When I switch to the dowork wizard I want the four views for dowork to show.

Do I have to write my own view manager (or extensions) to do this work? Am I completely thinking about it incorrectly? Note that I do not want to have a SignupRegion and a DoWorkRegion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to come up with some sort of view manager on your own. I believe there are some frameworks out there with this sort of functionality.

Using Prism alone you could use the event aggregator service to send messages to make views visible/collapsed.

If you are doing MVVM you could also bind the visibility of those views to a service/controller class where those properties are set.

You can also use a combination of the two.

Comment: Shoot, was afraid of that. OK, I'll see what I can cook up. Thanks.